# Elastic textarea using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I attempted to make my own elastic textarea code for practice. This is what I currently have

```
$(".textareaField").keyup(function() {
    var height = $(this).height();

    var lines = $(this).val().split('\n');
    var line_count = lines.length;
    var total_lines = 8;

    if(total_lines < line_count) {
        $(this).animate({
            "height" : (line_count * 25)
        }, 200);
    } else {
        $(this).animate({
            "height" : 200
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

`total_lines` is the number of lines possible in that textarea, its 8 because the initial height of textarea is 200 px and line-height is 25 px. 200/25 = 8 lines possible on initial config. What I want to achieve is to shorten the textarea when the user deletes couple of lines, and stop reducing the height at 8 lines (200 px).

Comment: I am so sorry for misunderstanding but I have found that the script works as is and needs to further changes, I just tested it. I shouldve tested some more before posting this question. But well, there you have it an elastic textarea

Comment: So from what i gather, you want the textarea to expand as the user types, and contract as the user deletes... Correct?

If that's the case, i wouldn't do it this way. If you decide to change the font, font-size or line height, it will break your script.

Comment: http://www.technoreply.com/autogrow-textarea-plugin-version-2-0/

Comment: @Combat.... Please explain: You have a web page and there's a textarea... you give users the possibility to play with the font-size inside a textarea?

Comment: No. You may decide to change the styling later on. Would you then want to go through and edit all your javascript later?

Comment: @Combat, I, the developer will set the line-height thus not give the users the option to change it. And yes, that's exactly what I wanted to do and looks like I achieved it.

Comment: @biziclop that textarea is ugly, there is a big bottom padding when new line is added.

Comment: @Grigor ~ I second Combat on his concern. Yeah, you're the dev, and you dictate the line height and textarea height. What he means is that, what happens if you want to use your code on another project, and this time you want your textarea to start off at 300px, with a line-height of, say, 8pt? You'll have to change your Javascript code. A more elegant solution is to have your code automatically adjust to the textarea styling, and work from there.

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan Yes I agree with both of you, this plugin was created about at the time when I posted it. I will change all the properties that need to be retrieved not assigned. Thanks for pointing out though.